# Javascript: Trying to make form submit button open in new window, link determined by radio buttons

Tags: javascript, window.open

```
<script>
function onRadioClick(radio) {
  radio.form.action = radio.value;
}
function onFormSubmit(form) {
  window.location = form.action;
  return false;   
}
</script>

<form name="input" action="#" method="get" onsubmit="window.open.return onFormSubmit(this)">
<label><input type="radio" name="destination" onclick="onRadioClick(this)" value="yes.html" />YES!</label><label><input type="radio" name="destination" 

onclick="onRadioClick(this)" value="no.html"/>No</label>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

I don't understand why the "window.open" isn't working. The submit button opens the link in the current tab. I got it to work right once and I thought it was this exact code, but I didn't save my work and now I can't get it to work again.

Comment: Try adding `target="_blank"` to `<form>`. That should make it open in a new window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
```

(or)this

```
<form target="_blank" ...></form>
```

Comment: Oh, I finally got it. I'd tried this numerous times already without success, but just found that it works when I combine it with `"window.open(return onFormSubmit(this))"` . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax error:
`onsubmit="window.open.return onFormSubmit(this)"`

Try this:

`onsubmit="window.open('the url')"`

or this:

`onsubmit="return onFormSubmit(this)"`

Comment: the `target="_blank"` addition to `<form>` won't work. No idea why. And Robrich both of these work, but neither accomplish what I want. I want it to rely on the link provided by each radio button, AND open in new window.

By the way, sorry if I'm a little difficult. I'm brand new to Javascript but I've been playing around with it for a few hours.